# Why does TreeView.OnBeforeSelect loop?

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

So I have a treeview and I want to be able to deselect a node by clicking it.

I'm extending the treeview class (need some other functionality as well) but I've run into a little issue.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
     protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnNodeMouseClick(e);
        if (this.SelectedNode == e.Node)
        {
            this.SelectedNode = null;
            selectedSame = true;
        }
    }


    protected override void OnBeforeSelect(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedSame)
        {
            selectedSame = false;
            base.OnBeforeSelect(e);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

What happens is after e.cancel is called, it loops back around through OnBeforeSelect, and now it's false so it then selects it (undoing what I just did!).

I took the selectedSame = false; out of the OnBeforeSelect and put it in a condition elsewhere, but then this piece runs for infinity and never breaks!

```
    if (selectedSame)
        {
            selectedSame = false;
            base.OnBeforeSelect(e);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

also tested with just:

```
    protected override void OnBeforeSelect(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {

            base.OnBeforeSelect(e);
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

And it also just loops a zillion times (if I take the break off it actually finishes, but if I put it back on and click it enters it's loop of however many hundred times).

I guess I don't really understand how e.Cancel is supposed to work, because it seems like as soon as it hits cancel it jumps right back around without even finishing that call.

Any advice would be most appreciated :)

-Wright

Edit: - More Information

Made a brand new project to be sure none of the events I was was hooked into were causing this problem. Same result, but it did lead me to discover at least the steps it's taking. When I set "this.SelectedNode = null" it triggers the OnBeforeSelect which causes the whole thing to get all messed up in the first place. But if I have a button, which when clicked, sets the tree's selectednode to null, OnBeforeSelect never happens. So what's the difference?

Final:

No code in extended class other than this:

```
    class StatedTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    {
    protected override void OnBeforeSelect(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
            {
            e.Cancel = true;            
            }
    }
```

If you put a break on the cancel...it just loops and loops and loops. If you take the break off, the program becomes somewhat usable (selects and then instantly cancels, which is good). But if you add the break back while it's running it instantly breaks on it again! You don't even have to select a node! Ugh...I don't get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a debugger induced artifact.  The debugger tries to stay out of the way of the program as much as it can.  But there are some inevitable side-effects from having it break on a breakpoint.  Which tends to make debugging UI events difficult.  A Paint event handler tends to be tricky for example.

The issue here is that the focus changes, from your program to Visual Studio.  And you have the TreeView.HideSelection property set to True.  So the focus change in fact unselects the current tree node.  When you resume execution, the focus goes back to the TreeView and it selects the node again.  Which triggers the OnBeforeSelect() method again.  Which triggers the breakpoint again, etcetera, etcetera.

In extreme cases you may need to use the remote debugger to get past these side-effects.  But you don't have to go that far, afaict your code is good.  Setting HideSelection to false fixes it, in case you need to continue debugging this.

Comment: This may be part of the problem. But I had read on a different forum about the HideSelection = false. And have had that set this entire time. It still does the never ending cancel loop. But it may still be that the debugger itself is causing this. Though that doesn't really explain why if I take it off, then just put it back on it instantly catches it again.

Comment: Well, add a Console.WriteLine() to the method so you can see this reported in the Output window without having to use a debugger breakpoint.  I tested your first snippet that way and saw no recursion problems.

Comment: This does actually seem to be the problem. I moved all of my logic inside the OnNodeMouseClick() method so the actions will take place before before triggering the event that the main form will capture (NodeClicked), and just use a cancel bool inside the OnBefore to cancel it if need be. Seems to be working well!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because you keep calling again and again the `OnBeforeSelect` Event? You are calling recursively the event without any stop condition (since `e.Cancel = true;` is **after** the call to the event).

Are you sure you need to call `base.OnBeforeSelect` ? if so, you might wanna call `e.Cancel = true;` before.

Comment: Sorry I left that part out. I actually tried it with just e.Cancel, but then it just loops infinitely...

        if (selectedTwiceRemove)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

I don't know what's making it call OnBeforeSelect over and over and over even with cancel. I just want it to stop!